# Retrieve email from Facebook login in a Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise, omniauth-facebook

I'm trying to create a Rails 4 app with Facebook login using devise and omniauth-facebook gem.

I followed this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-devise-and-omniauth-for-your-rails-application

Right now, I can save a user in the database, but email gets null.

I already tried another tutorials, all of them getting the same, email null.

I noticed that when I click on the "Sign in" button, I get the following link:

https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=1452548131713566&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.4%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fusers%252Fauth%252Ffacebook%252Fcallback%26state%3Db9cfa351943875b105b0b9206a5de31d6fbed43cda4a59d3%26scope%3Demail%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3D1452548131713566%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26state%3Db9cfa351943875b105b0b9206a5de31d6fbed43cda4a59d3%23_%3D_&display=page

It seems like a permission error, but I can't seem to figure it out why.

Here it is the self.from_omniauth method:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
       user.provider = auth.provider
       user.uid = auth.uid
       user.name = auth.info.name
       user.email = auth.info.email
       user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
     end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post `self.from_omniauth(auth)` method from `user.rb`?

Comment: Added self.from_omniauth method.

Answer (score 0):

Could You Please Check params by using

```
raise params.inspect
```

on the callback page action as when,facebook says that app is sharing user's email.It sends the json data from its system to your callback url.

Comment: #<OmniAuth::AuthHash credentials=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash expires=true expires_at=1441975055 token="CAAUpFbdo8h4BALL5IN4AZBOF53hrWNPQpKkj27QNTZAir7tr3lufZBMraQrd7crIr7nXtsCFoBVgTC8wvvkNaYQ1tlaxdDgGENZB5WW2dCte3ZB3ZA6NXVNGGXxXbpXVZBZCCGV1ymlFr2gWk1ZA3UnSJhqnAHwJvtZAVDnkPai3G0XHXXkzNVnBhEVPRKNIzLc4ybTurDgVJRh3vf1JsdfWhW"> extra=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash raw_info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash id="1026775354001539" name="Tiago Almeida">> info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash image="http://graph.facebook.com/1026775354001539/picture" name="Tiago Almeida"> provider="facebook" uid="1026775354001539">

Comment: Try to add this in devise.rb:

`config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET",  {:scope => 'email,...'}`

Answer (score 0):

The api changed on 8 of July.

This did it:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "appid", "appsecret", scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email'
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4